# How to reduce an array with the depth of a particular property

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

### Input

Below is an object I am trying to reduce

```json
  data = [
    {
      id: "m1",
      name: "menu1",
      val: "D",
      items: [
        {
          id: "d1",
          name: "datanested1",
          val: "D",
          items: [
            { id: "1", name: "direct Data", val: "E" },
            { id: "2", name: "test", val: "E" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "d2",
      name: "menu2",
      val: "D",
      items: [
        { id: "21", name: "test21", val: "E" },
        { id: "22", name: "test23", val: "E" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "d3",
      name: "menu3",
      val: "D",
      items: [
        { id: "31", name: "test data 3", val: "E" },
        { id: "32", name: "test data 4", val: "E" }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

### Output

My expectation is that the object reduced to below

```json
[
  {
    "id": "m1",
    "name": "menu1",
    "val": "D",
    "depth": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "d1",
    "name": "datanested1",
    "val": "D",
    "parentId": "m1",
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "direct Data",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d1",
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d1",
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "d2",
    "name": "menu2",
    "val": "D",
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "test23",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d2",
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "21",
    "name": "test21",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d2",
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "d3",
    "name": "menu3",
    "val": "D",
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "32",
    "name": "test data 4",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d3",
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "31",
    "name": "test data 3",
    "val": "E",
    "parentId": "d3",
    "depth": 0
  }

]
```

### Explanation

depth is the number of levels of the property `.items` for example

property with  `id: "1"` has 0 children generation for property `items`, its depth value is `0` 
property with  `id: "2"` has 0 children generation for property `items`, its depth value is `0` 
property with  `id: "d1"` has 1 children generation for property `items`, its depth value is `1` 
property with  `id: "m1"` has 2 children generation for property `items`, its depth value is `2` 
...

### My current Approach

Below is what I currently have

```js
function reducedArray(myArray) {
    let newReduced = myArray;
    let noMoreItems = false;
    while (!noMoreItems) {
      newReduced = newReduced.reduce((prev, next) => {
        const parent = { ...next };
        delete parent.items;
        if (!parent.depth) {
          parent.depth = 0;
        } else {
          parent.depth = parent.depth + 1;
        }
        if (!next.items) {
          return [parent, ...prev];
        }
        return [
          parent,
          ...prev,
          ...next.items.map(item => ({
            ...item,
            parentId: next.id
          }))
        ];
      }, []);

      noMoreItems = true;
      noMoreItems = !newReduced.find(({ items }) => items);
    }
    return newReduced;
  }
  
  const myArray = [{"id":"m1","name":"menu1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"d1","name":"datanested1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"1","name":"direct Data","val":"E"},{"id":"2","name":"test","val":"E"}]}]},{"id":"d2","name":"menu2","val":"D","items":[{"id":"21","name":"test21","val":"E"},{"id":"22","name":"test23","val":"E"}]},{"id":"d3","name":"menu3","val":"D","items":[{"id":"31","name":"test data 3","val":"E"},{"id":"32","name":"test data 4","val":"E"}]}];
  
  console.log(reducedArray(myArray))
```

### Challenges

The approach seems to reduce the array as expected, the challenge is that the depth is not maintained, plus the order is not as expected. The order is important as this is to be used to generate a UI in the form

```
  menu1
      datanested1
         direct Data
         test
```

The depth property will be used to format the indentation

Please assist in debugging or suggeting how I can transform this data

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple recursive approach.  Depth is "backwards" to what you expected but it's easier to fix that afterwards (or use it as is).

```js
function handleArray(arr, depth, parentId) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const {items, ...otherProps} = el;
    acc.push({...otherProps, parentId, depth});
    if (items) {
      return acc.concat(handleArray(items, depth + 1, el.id));
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
  
  const myArray = [{"id":"m1","name":"menu1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"d1","name":"datanested1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"1","name":"direct Data","val":"E"},{"id":"2","name":"test","val":"E"}]}]},{"id":"d2","name":"menu2","val":"D","items":[{"id":"21","name":"test21","val":"E"},{"id":"22","name":"test23","val":"E"}]},{"id":"d3","name":"menu3","val":"D","items":[{"id":"31","name":"test data 3","val":"E"},{"id":"32","name":"test data 4","val":"E"}]}];
  
console.log(handleArray(myArray, 0, ""));
```

Comment: This looks promising, let me see if I can implement it in my current situation

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursive approach with `reduce` but you also need separate recursive call to get depth so that you can get both desired order of elements and also correct depth results.

```js
const data = [{"id":"m1","name":"menu1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"d1","name":"datanested1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"1","name":"direct Data","val":"E"},{"id":"2","name":"test","val":"E"}]}]},{"id":"d2","name":"menu2","val":"D","items":[{"id":"21","name":"test21","val":"E"},{"id":"22","name":"test23","val":"E"}]},{"id":"d3","name":"menu3","val":"D","items":[{"id":"31","name":"test data 3","val":"E"},{"id":"32","name":"test data 4","val":"E"}]}]

function fDepth(data, lvl = 1) {
    return data.reduce((r, { items }) => {
        return items ? fDepth(items, lvl + 1) : lvl;
    }, lvl);
}

function f(data, parentId = null) {
    return data.reduce((r, { id, name, val, items }) => {
        const obj = { id, name, val };

        if (parentId) obj.parentId = parentId;
        obj.depth = items ? fDepth(items) : 0;

        r.push(obj);

        if (items) r.push(...f(items, id));

        return r;
    }, []);
}

const result = f(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer, It actually fulfills my requirement